# Voltage between 2 points of net electropositivity

Tags: electricity, voltage

Ok, so suppose we have 2 points that are overall electropositive but one is "less positive" than the other. Say point A is +50 V and point B is +20V. How will we calculate the potential difference between two such points or is that even a possible scenario? Also would we assign a negative sign to the +20 V while subtracting the two?

Answer (score 0):

The potential difference is $50-20=30\,\rm V$.
Think of it akin to a difference between a height of $20\,\rm m$ and one of $50\,\rm m$.

Answer (score 0):

All potentials are essentially arbitrary in the sense we can add a constant to all of the values and have the same scenario<sup>1</sup>.  Voltages are no different.  For any case, the voltage difference is just the difference in the potentials, the same as it would be if one were positive and one negative.

$$V_{12} = \Phi_1 - \Phi_2$$
$$V_{12} = 50  - 20$$
$$V_{12} = 30$$

1 - For a favorite reference of mine see [Torsors Made Easy](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html), quoted below:

> In electromagnetism, we can only measure voltage differences, not
> voltages themselves. The reason is that we can add any real number to
> our definition of the electromagnetic potential without changing any
> of the physics. In practical work with electrical circuits, we usually
> say the electromagnetic potential of the ground is zero. But this is
> an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, if the potential difference is 30V then will it be 30V at any point between the two points or will it be 30V only between the two terminal ends? Let's say we have a box split into 10 compartments and the voltage between the 2 ends of the box is 30V . Does that mean that this 30V will be divided equally amongst these 10 compartments or do all these compartments have 30V of voltage?